# How to repeat text animation continuously again and again

Tags: jquery, html

I am using below code for animate the text continually again and again but the below code is ending with 10 cases which i mentioned in the code below but i required the text is animate again and again.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery TextFX - A jQuery Text Animation Engine</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{margin:0;padding:0;color:#333}#effectTwo{display:none}
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cj-text-fx.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cj-text-fx.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var isOn = 0,
sets, fx, toAnimate = "#effect",
settings = {
    animation: 8,
    animationType: "in",
    backwards: !1,
    easing: "easeOutQuint",
    speed: 1E3,
    sequenceDelay: 100,
    startDelay: 0,
    offsetX: 100,
    offsetY: 50,
    onComplete: fireThis,
    restoreHTML: !0
};
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    fx = jQuery("#effect");
    jQuery.cjTextFx(settings);
    jQuery.cjTextFx.animate(toAnimate)
});

function fireThis() {
    if (isOn !== 13) {
        isOn < 13 ? isOn++ : isOn = 0;
        switch (isOn) {
        case 1:
            sets = {
                animationType: "out",
                restoreHTML: !1
            };
            break;
        case 2:
            fx.html("Systematic Approch for Innovation");
            sets = {
                animation: 11
            };
            break;
        case 3:
            sets = {
                animation: 11,
                animationType: "out",
                restoreHTML: !1
            };
            break;
        case 4:
            fx.html("Systematic Approch for Innovation");
            sets = {
                animation: 1
            };
            break;
        case 5:
            sets = {
                animation: 1,
                animationType: "out",
                restoreHTML: !1
            };
            break;
        case 6:
            fx.html("Systematic Approch for Innovation");
            sets = {
                animation: 6,
                backwards: !0
            };
            break;
        case 7:
            sets = {
                animation: 4,
                animationType: "out",
                backwards: !0,
                restoreHTML: !1
            };
            break;
        case 8:
            fx.html("Systematic Approch for Innovation");
            sets = {
                animation: 2,
                easing: "easeOutBounce"
            };
            break;
        case 9:
            sets = {
                animation: 2,
                animationType: "out",
                speed: 500,
                easing: "easeInBack",
                restoreHTML: !1
            };
            break;
        case 10:
            fx.html("Systematic Approch for Innovation"), sets = {
                animation: 14,
                startDelay: 1E3,
                linked: !0,
                hyperlink: "generator.html",
                color: "#0000FF",
                linkTarget: "_self",
                onComplete: null
            }
        }
        jQuery.cjTextFx.animate(toAnimate, sets)
    }
};

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="text-fx">
    <div id="effect">Systematic Approch for Innovation</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please show me a way to solve the problem. it is urgent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you no format the code perfectly?:D

Comment: Seriously, did you swipe this off of someone else's site and now you want to use it as your own after changing one variable, but you don't know which one to change?  I honestly can't think of another reason why you'd post minified code (!) that you "urgently" need help on modifying.  Very uncool.  If you're going to steal someone else's code, at least put in some minimum amount of effort to get it to do what you want it to do so that you can honestly claim that you're just using it as an example to learn from.  >:-(

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 if (isOn !== 13) {
 isOn < 13 ? isOn++ : isOn = 0;
```

and

```
 case 10:
        fx.html("Systematic Approch for Innovation"), sets = {
            animation: 14,
            startDelay: 1E3,
            linked: !0,
            hyperlink: "generator.html",
            color: "#0000FF",
            linkTarget: "_self",
            onComplete: null
        }
    }
    jQuery.cjTextFx.animate(toAnimate, sets)
```

To:

```
    isOn !== 11 ? isOn++ : isOn = 0;
```

and

```
 case 10:
        fx.html("Systematic Approch for Innovation"), sets = {
            animation: 14,
            startDelay: 1E3,
            linked: !0,
            hyperlink: "generator.html",
            color: "#0000FF",
            linkTarget: "_self",
            onComplete: function(){
                 jQuery.cjTextFx.animate(toAnimate, sets)
            }
        }
    }
```